# How to get difference from 2 arrays for each values

Tags: java, arraylist

How can I get the difference from 2 arrays

Input:

```
 List<Integer> bookingList = (3,4,5,6,5,5);
 List<Integer> bookedList = (1,2,3,2,3,4);
```

What I want to do is pointwise subtraction

`bookingList.get(i) - bookedList.get(j)
//i is the position
//j is the position`

The result should be a new `List` with the following content:

`List<Integer> finalList = (2,2,2,4,2,1)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you are:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        caluclateFinalList();
    }

    private static void caluclateFinalList() {
        List<Integer> bookingList = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(3, 4, 5, 6, 5, 5));
        List<Integer> bookedList = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3, 2, 3, 4));

        // Output list
        List<Integer> finalList = new ArrayList<>(bookingList.size());

        // Loop
        for (int position = 0; position < bookedList.size(); position++) {
            // Calculate result
            int result = bookingList.get(position) - bookedList.get(position);
            // Add result to final list
            finalList.add(result);
        }

        // Print final list to the console
        System.out.println(finalList);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If the lists are guaranteed to be the same size then you can simply do a `for` loop.

```
List<Integer> results = new ArrayList(bookingList.size());
for(int i= 0; i < bookingList.size(); i++) {
      results.add(bookingList.get(i) - bookedList.get(i));
}
return results;
```

This gives you the differences inside results and within `O(n)` where `n` is the size of the arrays.

If the arrays are not the same size, you obviously need to check for some index bounds. I'm not sure whether you want to consider the excess elements and just add them to the result, or if you want to discard them, but a simple modification to the algorithm above can get your there.

Comment: Your answer is correct but I'll use the answer below thanks anyway